# gtk: find if a widget is from some type

Tags: python-2.7, pygtk, equality

I'm trying to find whether some widget in gtk is a ComboBox widget.
The **is** word dont seem to work here

```
def set_entries_editable(self, bool, widget):
    '''define whether to enable/disable widget'''
        if widget is gtk.ComboBoxEntry:
            widget.set_sensitive(bool)
        else:
            widget.set_editable(bool)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`is`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#is) is used to check object identity.

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> b = [1, 2]
>>> a is b
False
>>> a is a
True
```

Use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) to check whether the object is instance of specific type:

```
>>> isinstance(a, list)
True
```

---

```
if isinstance(widget, gtk.ComboBoxEntry):
```